# service discovery of consul from a monolith application

Tags: consul, spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-consul

I have a monolith application A, which needs to invoke a microservice B via service discovery . Consul is the service discovery server used. Microservice B is registered with the Consul server.

From A i am able to invoke B by giving `http://hostname:portname/endpoint`

How to do this via service discovery.

I tried adding the dependency `spring-cloud-dependencies`  in Monolith Application A so that i can use `org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient`   to do the service discovery, but this spring dependency is bringing in embedded tomcat jar which is clashing with my jboss as both run on the default port of `8080` . converting monolith A into a springboot app just for the sake of service discovery isnt an option.

Is there a non spring option to do service discovery from a monolith application to a Consul server?

Comment: This is exactly what I looking for. Imagine that there are already 50 microservices written in SparkJava, and I want to integrate them with Consul for service discovery, but is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to lookup the consul server from monolith application. Add a dependency in your pom.xml

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.orbitz.consul/consul-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.orbitz.consul</groupId>
    <artifactId>consul-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The below method will return the hostname,port like `http://hostname:port`  on which the services are running and as registered on consul

```
public String serviceUrl(String serviceName) {
        String consulRegistryHost = System.getProperty("consul.registry.url");
        Consul consul = Consul.builder().withUrl(consulRegistryHost).build(); // connect to Consul on localhost by default , otherwise
        HealthClient healthClient = consul.healthClient();

        List<ServiceHealth> nodes = healthClient.getAllServiceInstances(serviceName).getResponse(); // discover only "passing" nodes
        if (nodes != null && nodes.size() > 0 ) {
            ServiceHealth node = nodes.get(0);
            return "http://"+node.getService().getAddress()+":"+node.getService().getPort();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: this is client side load balancing, you'll have to continuously monitor the state of instances, come up with load balancing algorithm (round robin, ...) and handle errors. you asked about an external way to do it, please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Consul aware loadbalancer such as https://traefik.io/ or https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio or a client-side load balancing solution such as https://linkerd.io/